# How do I install this script?

Tags: php, installation, bitcoin

So I need help installing this script: github.com/Crypton33/CryptoPonzi. I’ve completed the config and set up the rest on my VPS (I have Apache, PHP, MySQL).

My question is, where do I put the files?

I want to run the setup.php but I’m not sure how to do it. Obviously, I wouldn’t put them in /var/www/.

Thanks NOTE: Bitcoind is setup.

Comment: Address: 1Phea1B22qBWMe9gAdDBzeVWsHDfeYJ2NV

Answer (score 1):

Well I think you can just put it in /var/www, run it and then delete it.

Or you can run `php setup.php` in terminal and it should work.

Comment: I will try to do it now